# Jboss Drools - Create rule "on the fly"

Tags: drools, dsl, rule-engine, business-rules, drools-guvnor

1. To create a new rule in Drools, do I need to have all classes declared in the rule already deployed?
2. A business person can create a new rule and deploy it "on the fly"? What I mean is a hot deploy of this new rule, without coding, compiling and redeploy anything.

Ideas?

Comment: Please define *exactly* what you mean by "create", "deploy" and "redeploy". - But I can tell you right now that *nothing* is possible "without coding, compiling and redeploying *anything*". (Emphasis on "anything" added by me.)

Comment: What I mean is:

The rule engine is running and, at this moment, I need a business person to create a new rule and deploy it in this running environment without intervention of developers.

The business person create a rule, save it and the rule will be running at that moment on.

Comment: You'll need to create a new knowledge base and start another session from it. Since the old session may contain "state" in several forms, this may require some transfer operations. - All in all, it's a risky business, and no "business person" should be permitted to do this without proper supervision. - There may be other ways of achieving what you think of doing, but you'll have to provide an example outlining the limitations of the rule the "business person" may be at liberty to concoct.